# What is the ConTeXt equivalent of LaTeX “\@.”

Tags: spacing, punctuation, context, best-practices, frenchspacing

In English text, TeX follows the convention of putting extra space after a period by default, which I like.  However, in the case of abbreviations it causes a problem.  To suppress the extra space, one can use `\`  or `~`, which is useful for lower case abbreviations such as “e.g.”

Unfortunately, for upper-case abbreviations, TeX archaically assumes that the period is part of the abbreviation, and uses a narrow space.  You can force a wide space in LaTeX via the `\@.` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Wrong: \\
First.  An abbreviation, e.g. PC.  Second. \\
First.  An abbreviation, e.g.\ PC\@.  Second. \\
:Right
\end{document}
```

In ConTeXt, this causes an error – the `\@.` macro is not defined.

```
\starttext
Wrong: \\
First.  An abbreviation, e.g. PC.  Second. \\
First.  An abbreviation, e.g.\ PC\@.  Second. \\  % Error here.
:Right
\stoptext
```

So, is there an equivalent of `\@.` for ConTeXt?

Comment: For what it's worth, the simple definition of `\@` in LaTeX is `\def\@{\spacefactor1000 }` and the same definition should have the same effect in ConTeXt

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not aware that ConTeXt has an equivalent for `\@`. But it's easy to build, since it just uses `\spacefactor`.

```
\define\fullstop
  {\spacefactor\plusthousand}

\starttext
  An abbreviation, e.g. PC. Second.           \\
  An abbreviation, e.g. PC\fullstop. Second.  \\
  An abbreviation, e.g.\ PC.\ Second.         \\
  An abbreviation, e.g. PC.\ Second.          \\
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: +1 for using a readable name `\fullstop` instead of `\@`.

Comment: @Aditya problem with `\fullstop` as opposed to `\@` is that it eats the trailing spaces in case you use it as `e.g.\@ PC` which I a lot prefer over `e.g.\ PC` That is the reason why a non-letter one-symbol control sequence is used for this. In LaTeX, the correct form is of course: `An abbreviation, e.g.\@ PC\@. Second.`

Comment: @tohecz: Thanks, I had no idea “\@” was that general.  The main disadvantage from my point of view is that “\@” is really not fun to search the web for!

Comment: well, `\spacefactor1000` _after_ the `.` tells TeX that the following space is a normal inter-word space. But if you put it _before_ the dot, TeX doesn't see what was before, so even if it was `PC` before, TeX considers the `.` to be a full stop. It is a bit crazy distinction between `.\@` and `\@.` that took me some time to understand.